# Vaadin - how to pass actors into UI elements

Tags: scala, servlets, akka, vaadin

I've just started using Vaadin and I have a simple Vaadin project defining 2 servlets and their associated Vaadin UI classes. My question relates to how to architect a "push" style system to pass information between UI instances.

The first servlet is responsible for gathering data from users (through say a `DataUI`), then storing it in a database.

The second servlet is responsible for reporting on the gathered data with graphs etc... (through say a `ReportUI`). There may be many instances of this for different customers viewing different sets of data relevant to them.

I wanted an architecture where a centralised `ActorSystem` (sitting on the server) creates and passes `ActorRef` instances to each `DataUI` as it's created. When the `DataUI` gathers some data, it sends it as a message through its `ActorRef` then closes. Likewise each `ReportUI` has an `ActorRef` passed into it which would listen for new data relevant to its report, and update the UI accordingly.

My problem is that I don't understand the Vaadin infrastructure well enough to see how you can pass references (like actors) into UI components when they're constructed. UI objects seem to be instantiated using something analogous to reflection and can only be passed information through request objects or by accessing string parameters set in say the web.xml file. How do you do dependency injection with Vaadin UI objects?

I know that it is possible to get this kind of behaviour by using globally accessible singleton objects - but I would like an architecture where I can unit test each component in isolation (for example by passing in mock actors) without having them hard-wired up to a global singleton object or a database.

Is there a standard way this is achieved? Any help or advice on a good architecture would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

I am currently using

- vaadin 7.1.12
- javax servlet 2.5
- akka 2.1.2

Also I'm using scala 2.10.3 and the Scaladin wrapper library (scaladin_2.10-3.0.0.jar) - but any basic Java examples would still be much appreciated - I'm more interested in seeing the higher level architecture.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Every UI, after being constructed for you, invokes the `protected void init(VaadinRequest request)` method. Here you can get a suitable Actor, for instance based on the request parameters (i.e. the URL that invoked the UI), or from a factory class that you could configure in web.xml.

As this would still ultimately leave the UI in charge of creating the references, you could go for real dependency intjection via the Vaadin/CDI extension. This would allow you to really @Inject your dependencies into the UI. But this is currently in alpha state, not sure if that would be acceptable. I've used it and for basic @Inject stuff it seems to work quite nicely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm aware of the `init` method, but it seems that this just pushes the essential problem back one step. The servlet will still be hard-wired in some sense to an actor factory and will still essentially be responsible for creating its own actors, rather than having the dependencies passed into it.